# can't install libgl1-mesa-glx

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64 and I really need to install libgl1-mesa-glx.
First I install with this command

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Then I got this errors

```
aungthiha@aungthiha:~$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (=
8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7)
                        Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried this.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal:i386
```

Similar error Occur

```
aungthiha@aungthiha:~$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal:i386
[sudo] password for aungthiha: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-quantal:i386 (=  
9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
                                Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal:i386 (>= 
7.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
aungthiha@aungthiha:~$
```

how do I solve this. Please, help!

Comment: simple command will does the job,`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx`

Comment: The same error occur sir

Comment: @AungThiha have you tried with the procedures mentioned on the link?